# div wrapper width by min content

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I make row with items. Each item contains a title, image, and button. Images keep their aspect-ratio.
I dont understand why wrapper add empty space.

Sandbox:
https://codepen.io/krosert/pen/QWNNVxg

**Now result:**

[image: actual result]

**Expected Result:**

[image: expected result]

code:

```
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="item">
        <span class="title">first item</span>
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/JQMJ3BW/2311f3c1-2802-417f-9b7e-2147f066e260.jpg">
        <div class="btns">
          <button>1</button>
          <button>2</button>
          <button>3</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <span class="title">second item</span>
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/wMyyz1n/934tvi5uykv2.jpg">
        <div class="btns">
          <button>1</button>
          <button>2</button>
          <button>3</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
    .panel{
      position: fixed;
      background-color: #685;
      top: 30px;
      height: 200px;
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .item{
      margin: 6px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      background-color: #553;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-start;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
      max-width: 300px;
    }
    img {
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      min-height: 0;
      min-width: 0;
    }
```

Comment: `flex-direction: column;` This will care about height, and let the width be a variable chrome fixes this because it recalculates FF doesn't becuase it may result in an infinite loop, Question is Which one of the three elements should define the width of  `.item` ? because right now it is the largest item which is the image before resizing that why there's left over space

Comment: Define width .item should max width (title or image or btns). I understand what you are talking about. How i can force calculate width .item after image downscale resizing?

Comment: It can't be max image because the browser will only consider the first size in this case you have to resize the images yourself before using them, And you can't force calculation in FF, in chrome if needed you can do it using an animation

Comment: 1) mb can it do if set original size  width \ height in img attribute ? Its can help browser right  calculate with for .item ?  2) Can you fix my example for work in chrome (' chrome if needed you can do it using an animation')

Comment: It already works fine for me in windows Chrome 83 (64-bit)

Comment: ? my screen from chrome 84. dont work :)  Try clear cache

Comment: My idea, We know that the images are the widest/tallest element, So Instead of limiting the parent height, apply `height:200px` to the images.

Answer (score 0):

remove `align-items: flex-start;` and add `object-fit: cover; object-position: top;`
to img

Comment: Result: Images croped. Does not match "Expected Result" 
 https://i.ibb.co/sQgzMp0/a3.png

Comment: because your images has different sizes, there is no way to show image without cropping and fill whole white spaces.

Answer (score -1):

remove this line:

```
.items {
align-items: flex-start;
}
```

What you are doing is telling the items element is to push the images to the start of their parent container column. Leaving the rest of the width as empty space.

To solve the issue with the image sizes overflowing their container, set a maximum height to the .items div:

```
.items{
  max-height: 95%;
}
```

Then set your images to not have a larger height than would cause it to overflow:

```
img {
  max-height: 140px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: And i get this: https://i.ibb.co/sCnpYBG/a1.png  Images out of line. does not match
 "Expected Result"

Comment: I have edited my post to address the issue you are experiencing. My answer was a direct response to your question in relation to the extra space created by the flex alignment. In my defence I didn't go on to finish your work for you because that wasn't what was requested. If you down-voted my answer I would kindly ask that you change your mind. Thanks

Comment: very bad solution with magic numbers, constant size... ps. i dont downvote

Comment: It isn't an ideal solution, no. But the issue is that you have images of different aspect ratios. So if you're applying one set of css stylings to all your images, it won't work like your "Expected Result". You can either expect to have your images at their native size which will expand outside your fixed "panel" container, or you will have to set them to have the same ratio depending on a fixed width or height: [example](https://ibb.co/5jY9Kyz)